# What do you call a function that maps within a type (or: space)

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

This question came up when I was trying to comment some code, but I think the language I'm looking for comes from category theory.

Suppose I have `f: X -> X`, where `X` is a type (integer, list, string, real numbers, etc.). How, terminologically, do I distinguish between that sort of function and the sort that moves between types (`f: X -> Y`)?

Comment: Mathematically the domain and range are part of the functions definition. Keeping strict control over these values is a core principle of functional programming. Everything has to be explicitly and well-defined.

Comment: @CyclotomicField OP is asking about the term for when domain and codomain same.

Comment: @coffeemath in that case I'd called it a function on $X$ in the same way we'd call a relation between $X$ and $X$ a relation on $X$.

Comment: "Endomap" or "endomorphism".

Comment: or "endofunction" in this case

Comment: The comments so far make some suggestions none of which are standard and all of which will sound strange. Are you sure you need a name for this property? You can [edit] to provide as sample sentence or paragraph that uses the word you seek.

Comment: @EthanBolker Well, "endomorphism" is entirely standard in category theory but probably not so much in functional programming.

Comment: I'm happy with endomorphism. Thanks.